# JavaScript - check for numbers in a text field

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

It takes in the value of a textfield, Im trying to have it so if any numbers are in the field then il be able to stop it.

```
 function hasNumbers(input) {

     var length = input.length;
     var end = 0;

     for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
         var char = input.substring(x, 1);
         trueFalse = isNaN(char);
         if (! trueFalse) {
             end++;
         }
     }

     if (end > 0) {
         return false;
     }

     return true;
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a problem?

Comment: `if (/^[^\d]+$/.test(value)) // value has no numbers`

Comment: Here it is so far: http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/29/

Comment: @Peter: I suggest you learn regular expressions, you're basically doing what regex do best, but messy and inefficiently.

Comment: See my answer for an example of how this can be done in one line with regular expressions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace your function with this:

```
function hasNumbers(input) {
    return /[0-9]/.test(input);
}
```

`/[0-9]/` constructs a regular expression that matches any numeric character.

Once you have a regex object, you can call *test(s)* to see if *s* matches the regex.

Here is [more information about the RegExp.test() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Here is [more info on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in general.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jZd7/) that shows the above code in action.

Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CD5L/2/) that shows the above function validating a text input.

Comment: I'm in the process of adding some explanation... This is essentially one of the most basic examples of how to use a _regular expression_. Regular expressions are a very powerful way to manipulate text and are available in most programming environments (you can also use them with grep, vi, and in many other places).   Once you start to learn how they work, you will be amazed!

Comment: Just this go through every char in the string or just 1? Thanks :)

Comment: The above function will return true if `input` contains any numbers.  It will return false otherwise.

Comment: There's a lot of unrelated code in your fiddle.  Here's a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jZd7/) that shows it works.

Comment: The first thing I notice about your fiddle is that the function _ValidateName_ is not getting called.  I added an alert to it, and it is not appearing when I edit (or leave) the Name input.  So... (as one might assume) your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you declare a variable named _HasNumbers_, which will cause problems if you try to invoke a function named _HasNumbers_.  **This is why I recommended using a debugger!!**  Using a debugger makes it **VERY SIMPLE** to find silly mistakes like this.  Without using a debugger it could take **HOURS** to troubleshooot your fiddle!  I launched Firebug, ran your fiddle once, and read the errors in the console.  The error message led me right to the problem immediately.

Comment: Here is [yet another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CD5L/2/) that shows it works.  This one uses my function to validate a text input.